# Study order of Fourier Analysis, Functional Analysis and Operator Theory?

Tags: functional-analysis, soft-question, fourier-analysis, operator-theory, advice

I hope my question is in the scope of MSE.

I want to study 1- Fourier Analysis, 2- Functional Analysis and 3- Operator Theory, all from scratch.

Which one I need to study first? second? and third? Or, can I study them parallel?

PS I know that I need advanced Real Analysis (for inclusion of Measure Theory). But I don't know what other primary mathematics is required for each of the mentioned three subject.

Edit - I have finished my BSc-maths and I want to learn all the three mentioned subject in graduate (MSc-maths(pure)) level.

Comment: It depends in the level you want to understand each of these. For example Operator theory can lead you to some pretty deep (and unexpected) areas of abstract algebra. From experience, I'd suggest mastering the "fundamental" material in analysis, topology and algebra and only then specializing your knowledge base. You don't really need functional analysis to "understand" Fourier analysis (ask any engineer) but any deep understanding will require an absolute mastery of functional analysis.

Comment: Also your background would be useful to offer more precise advice

Comment: @Wavelet, I edited OP. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I do not want this to come across as condescending in any way but most undergraduate mathematics programs in the US are guilty of teaching just enough to make their students dangerous. Self study is HARD. I can't stress enough how important it is that you constantly assess yourself. You have to learn to be skeptical of your understanding. You have to be willing to construct many different examples for each definition and theorem. Attempt the exercises and then try to poke holes in your solutions. My key piece of advice is to be patient above all else. True understanding is a marathon.

Comment: Also specific to your topics what is your current level of understanding in functional analysis? This is a good book that will get you started in both Fourier analysis and Operator theory: https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Hilbert-Spaces-Applications-Third/dp/0122084381/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1501971380&sr=8-1&keywords=hilbert+spaces+with+applications

Comment: @Wavelet, functional analysis was an optional course so I never took it, unfortunately. I just know undergraduate real analysis and self-studied Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis.

Comment: @Wavelet I love the way you put that! "Teaching just enough to make their students dangerous"! (I write as one who - through no fault of his university, it must be said - *learned* just enough to be "dangerous", as you aptly put it.)

Comment: You need to start with a course on Fourier series, then look at the Fourier transform.

Comment: Simon & Reed have written a series of books "Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics" where the first volume is called _Functional Analysis_, the second _Fourier Analysis, Self-adjointness_ and the fourth _Operator Theory_. The titles speak for themselves I think, but the books are rather advanced.

Comment: You might like this series: https://www.amazon.com/Elias-M.-Stein/e/B001IOFITU/ref=sr_ntt_srch_lnk_1?qid=1502212725&sr=8-1